# Select specific hour of mysql datetime field

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if there is a more accurate/correct method for selecting a specific hour of the given day when using a `datetime` field type.

This is what I am currently using, just wondering if there is a better or more proper way of doing this sql statement:

> SELECT ID FROM table WHERE DATE(SomeDateTimeStamp) = CURDATE() AND HOUR(SomeDateTimeStamp) = '11'

In that instance, I am checking for 11am, obviously.

Been hunting for a method to do this without doing a check on `DATE()` and a check on `HOUR()` but so far no luck finding a way. Is there, or is this going to be the best way to go about this?

I am running mysql 5.7.16

Answer (score 1):

To check for a specific day and hour you can do

```
SELECT ID 
FROM table 
WHERE SomeDateTimeStamp >= '2017-01-22 11:00:00'
  AND SomeDateTimeStamp < '2017-01-22 12:00:00'
```

which can make use of indexes.

Comment: Is this really the better way of doing it than using `DATE()` and `HOUR()` or are you just suggesting an alternative?

Comment: It is way faster and how I would do it.